# How do I turn off URI Encoding in HTTParty Post Body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, httparty

I'm trying to send a post to Paypal and they don't want anything to be URI encoded. But HTTParty seems to do this by default and it's breaking things for me. For a simple example, when I try this code:

```
HTTParty.post("http://google.com/", body: {foo: "http://example.com/bar"})
```

I see that the post body was actually

```
foo=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fbar
```

Is it possible to make HTTParty not perform the URI encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Run the class method query_string_normalizer with a proc that doesn't do any URI encoding. This worked for me.

```
query_string_normalizer proc { |query|
    query.map do |key, value|
        "#{key}=#{value}"
    end.join('&')
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it seems that space characters were still encoded (e.g. %20).  Special characters, like the @ in an email address were not - which is exactly what I needed.